# Python text to HTML link

Tags: python, html

Is there any way to convert plain text from my python shell into a HTML link?.
For example the string `http://bura.brunel.ac.uk/handle/2438/7216` should be converted to a link such that when I click it i get directed to the web page.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you asking to create a clickable link within your shell? This is trivial if you want to output a clickable link to a file but you want to do it within the shell?  I would think the way the shell responds to mouse clicks is going to limit that possibility.

Comment: @PyNEwbie  Yes I want a clickable link-either outputted to a file or from within the shell itself.How would i do it outputted to a file? –

Comment: You can't 'click' a link in a shell. They are usually text-only environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, if you wanted to open links from the shell, you can use the [`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module.

```
import webbrowser
urls = ['http://www.xkcd.org/',
        'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213479/python-text-to-html-link',
        'http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html']

for url in urls:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how you are generating the source for the link so I am going to pretend that you have a list of things you want to create clickable links for

```
my_url_list = ['http://www.stackoverflow.com','http://www.whitehouse.gov']

link_list = []
for each_url in my_url_list:
    link_string = '<a href = "'
    link_string = link_string + each_url
    link_string = link_string +'">' 
    link_name = each_url.split('.')[1]
    link_string = link_string + link_name + '</a><br>\n'
    link_list.append(link_string)


outref = open(mytemp.htm,'w')
outref.writelines(link_list)
outref.close()
```

The results before written out to a file look like

```
for each in link_list:
    each

'<a href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a><br>\n'
'<a href = "http://www.whitehouse.gov">whitehouse</a><br>\n'
```

Comment: @PyNEwbie....Thank you-That was exactly what I was looking for!!